# MobileFirst development server - analytics REST services

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-analytics

I'm running the development server under MobileFirst Studio 7.0 and I can see the analytics console with data reflecting my application's activities.

Previously in my production servers I have been able to interrogate the status of the Analytics engine by using REST requests such as

```
http://localhost:9500/_cluster/health?pretty=true
```

The port 9500 being configurable by JNDI entry

```
<jndiEntry jndiName="analytics/httpport"
       value="9501" />
```

this value defaults to 9500, while the transport port defaults to 9600.

In my development server I don't seem to be able to access these REST services Looking at the ports I can see that 9600 is active but 9500 is not, and the JNDI entry seems to have no effect.

I'm only seeking to do this for educational purposes, but am I missing something here? Is the REST capability expected to work in the development server? Is there some additional config I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0 this port was blocked for security reasons. However, some customers found it useful using that port so in a coming iFix there will be an option to override the security setting allowing you to view your analytics data on that port.